# update or delete on table "images" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm getting

> "delete from "images" where "id" = $1 - update or delete on table
>   "images" violates foreign key constraint "comments_image_id_foreign"
>   on table "comments

When deleting a image(or for a easier explanation post object) that **has comments**.

I'm using Knex and bookshelf

and using

[bookshelf-cascade-delete](https://github.com/seegno/bookshelf-cascade-delete)

I think i have it set up correctly .

**bookshelf**

```
import knex from 'knex';
import bookshelf from 'bookshelf';
import config from '../knexfile';
import cascadeDelete from 'bookshelf-cascade-delete';   
const herokuOrNot = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? config.development : config.production   

const Bookshelf = bookshelf(knex(herokuOrNot));
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');
Bookshelf.plugin(cascadeDelete);


export default Bookshelf;
```

**Image.js**

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';
import User from './User';
import Comment from './Comment';

const Image = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'images',
    timestamps: false,

    user(){
        return this.belongsTo(User);
    },
    dependents: ['comments'],
    comments(){
        return this.hasMany(Comment)
    }


});
```

and this is how its being deleted.

**image delete route**

```
router.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Image.forge({id:id}).fetch().then( (image) =>{
       return image.destroy().then( () => {
            return res.json({error: true, data: {message: 'Image Deleted'}})
        }).catch( (err) => {
           return res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message:err.message}});
        })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
      });
})
```

**images table**

```
export const up = async knex => {
    await knex.schema.createTable('images', (t) => {
        t.increments('id').primary().unsigned();
        t.string('image_title', 40);
        t.string('img_url', 250 );
        t.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        t.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        t.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users');
    })
};

export const down =  async knex => {
    await knex.schema.dropTable("images");
};
```

**comments table**

```
export const up = async knex => {
    await knex.schema.createTable('comments', (t) => {
        t.increments('id').primary().unsigned();
        t.string('comment_body', 500);
        t.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        t.timestamp('updated_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now());
        t.integer('user_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('users');
        t.integer('image_id').unsigned().references('id').inTable('images');
    })

};

export const down = async knex => {
    await knex.schema.dropTable("comments");
};
```

Comment: i fixed it. here is the solution

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple fix,

**Image.js** (old)

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';
import User from './User';
import Comment from './Comment';

const Image = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'images',
    timestamps: false,

    user(){
        return this.belongsTo(User);
    },
    dependents: ['comments'], // this doesn't go here.
    comments(){
        return this.hasMany(Comment)
    }


}, // goes here);
```

**Image.js** (new)

```
import bookshelf from '../config/bookshelf';
import User from './User';
import Comment from './Comment';

const Image = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'images',
    timestamps: false,

    user(){
        return this.belongsTo(User);
    },

    comments(){
        return this.hasMany(Comment)
    }


}, { dependents: ['comments']});
export default Image;
```